# How to install Packet Tracer 7.1.1 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am a newbie to Ubuntu OS, so don't really have much idea of how things work.
Well, m trying to install Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1.1, Now i don't really know how to do that. I have already downloaded Packettracer from the netacad.com.

Please if anyone can help me out here.

Thanks in Advance.

Also need help for installing VMware.

Comment: Have a look at the link on prior comment; its a different version of Ubuntu, but it'll likely be identical.

Comment: @mojo_jojo welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you need help with VMWare, you should start a new question. And definitely check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make sure that you include enough information in your question.